# Why do save and saveRDS act differently inside dopar?

Tags: r, foreach, machine-learning, parallel-processing, r-caret

(This is my first time trying to create a reproducible example question - please feel free to comment with better ways to describe or illustrate issues!)

***MAIN ISSUE STATEMENT***

I am training ~25,000 models in parallel using `foreach`'s `%dopar%` and `caretList` (from the `caretEnsemble` package). Due to R crashing and memory issues, I need to save each of the forecasts as an individual object, so my workflow looks something like this - see below for reproducible example.

```
cl <- makePSOCKcluster(4)
clusterEvalQ(cl, library(foreach))
registerDoParallel(cl)

multiple.forecasts <- foreach(x=1:1,.combine='rbind',.packages=c('zoo','earth','caret',"glmnet","caretEnsemble")) %dopar% {
  tryCatch({
    results <- caretList(mpg ~ cyl,data=mtcars,trControl=fitControl,methodList=c("glmnet","lm","earth"),continue_on_fail = TRUE)
    for (i in 1:length(results)) {
      results[[i]]$trainingData <- c() ## should be trimming out trainingData
    }
    save(results,file="foreach_results.Rdata") ## export each caretList as its own object
    1
  },
  error = function(e) {
    write.csv(e$message,file="foreach_failure.txt") ## monitor failures as needed
    0
  }
  )
}
```

(IRL this project does not involve the `mtcars` data - each iteration of the `foreach` loop iterates over one of the data frames in a list and saves a new forecast object for each data frame.)

When this object is saved inside the `foreach` loop, the object size is approximately 136 KB in Windows due to compression.

However, when this object is created and saved **not** using `foreach`, like so:

```
results <- caretList(mpg ~ cyl,data=mtcars,trControl=fitControl,methodList=c("glmnet","lm","earth"),continue_on_fail = TRUE)
for (i in 1:length(results)) {
    results[[i]]$trainingData <- c()
}
save(results,file="no_foreach_results.Rdata")
```

This object, which is about the same, is approximately 156KB in Windows. So what's adding to the saved object size in Windows?

In the real workflow, the smaller non-`foreach` object is about 4 MB on average and the larger `foreach` object is 10 MB on average, so this creates real storage issues when I am saving about ~25,000 of these files.

- **Why is the object size when saved within the foreach loop so much larger, and what if anything can I do about it?**

***NOTES***

- **My hypothesis is that `save` within `foreach` saves the entire environment**: instead of just saving the object, even when it's commanded to do so using `saveRDS` (see below), there is some implicit saving of the environment that was exported to each of the workers.
- **`Trim` doesn't seem to be working within `caretList`**: the `trim` `trainControl` option doesn't seem to be trimming what it's supposed to, as I had to manually add the command to trim the `trainingData`.
- **My current workaround is to set the `save` compression to `xz`**: I need the foreach loop to take advantage of multiple cores, so I need the larger objects. This slows down the workflow by about 3-4x however, which is why I'm looking for a solution.
- **The PSOCK cluster is needed to work around an issue in `caret` parallelization**: see the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24786089/parrf-on-caret-not-working-for-more-than-one-core).
- **`SaveRDS` does not help the issue**: I've tested using `saveRDS` instead of `save`, but the difference in object sizes pervades.
- **Removing the `tryCatch` does not help the issue**: Even without the `tryCatch` in the `foreach` loop, the difference in object size pervades.

***TECHNICAL DETAILS***

**Reproducible example:**

```
library(caret)
library(caretEnsemble)

## train a caretList without foreach loop
fitControl <- trainControl(## 10-fold CV
  method = "repeatedcv",
  number = 10,
  ## repeated ten times
  repeats = 10,
  trim=TRUE)

results <- caretList(mpg ~ cyl,data=mtcars,trControl=fitControl,methodList=c("glmnet","lm","earth"),continue_on_fail = TRUE)
for (i in 1:length(results)) {
    results[[i]]$trainingData <- c()
}
object.size(results) ##returns about 546536 bytes
save(results,file="no_foreach_results.Rdata") ##in Windows, this object is about 136 KB

## train a caretList with foreach loop
library(doParallel)

cl <- makePSOCKcluster(4)
clusterEvalQ(cl, library(foreach))
registerDoParallel(cl)

multiple.forecasts <- foreach(x=1:1,.combine='rbind',.packages=c('zoo','earth','caret',"glmnet","caretEnsemble")) %dopar% {
  tryCatch({
    results <- caretList(mpg ~ cyl,data=mtcars,trControl=fitControl,methodList=c("glmnet","lm","earth"),continue_on_fail = TRUE)
    for (i in 1:length(results)) {
      results[[i]]$trainingData <- c()
    }
    save(results,file="foreach_results.Rdata") ## in Windows, this object is about 160 KB
    ## loading this file back in and running object.size gives about 546504 bytes, approximately the same
    1
  },
  error = function(e) {
    write.csv(e$message,file="foreach_failure.txt")
    0
  }
  )
}
```

**sessionInfo() output:**

```
R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows Server 2012 x64 (build 9200)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] parallel  stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] doParallel_1.0.10   iterators_1.0.8     earth_4.4.4         plotmo_3.1.4        TeachingDemos_2.10 
 [6] plotrix_3.6-2       glmnet_2.0-5        foreach_1.4.3       Matrix_1.2-4        caretEnsemble_2.0.0
[11] caret_6.0-64        ggplot2_2.1.0       RevoUtilsMath_8.0.1 RevoUtils_8.0.1     RevoMods_8.0.1     
[16] RevoScaleR_8.0.1    lattice_0.20-33     rpart_4.1-10       

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.4        compiler_3.2.2     nloptr_1.0.4       plyr_1.8.3         tools_3.2.2       
 [6] lme4_1.1-11        digest_0.6.9       nlme_3.1-126       gtable_0.2.0       mgcv_1.8-12       
[11] SparseM_1.7        gridExtra_2.2.1    stringr_1.0.0      MatrixModels_0.4-1 stats4_3.2.2      
[16] grid_3.2.2         nnet_7.3-12        data.table_1.9.6   pbapply_1.2-1      minqa_1.2.4       
[21] reshape2_1.4.1     car_2.1-2          magrittr_1.5       scales_0.4.0       codetools_0.2-14  
[26] MASS_7.3-45        splines_3.2.2      pbkrtest_0.4-6     colorspace_1.2-6   quantreg_5.21     
[31] stringi_1.0-1      munsell_0.4.3      chron_2.3-47
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why either, but the workaround that I came up with is to just run

rm(train_data)

to remove anything heavy-duty storage-wise from the environment - the training dataset, for example - and stop it from being saved to disk.

(Glad it wasn't just me who this was driving crazy.)